# Visio clsEventSink library

Tags: vba, visio

I want to create a event object following the guide in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767482.aspx . A problem arises when I create a variable  as:

mEventSink As clsEventSink

I received a compile error: User-defined type not defined

I tried searching for a library for this but I am unable to find a source that give me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you've either placed all of the code into a single standard module, two separate ones, or not renamed the class module correctly but note from the instructions that you need to create a **class** module (ie not a standard module):

> Copy this sample code into a new **class** module in VBA or Visual Basic,
>   **naming the module clsEventSink**. You can then use the event-sink module
>   that follows to create an instance of the clsEventSink class and an
>   Event object for the MouseMove event that sends notifications of event
>   firings to the class instance.

So the first section of code, which implements the `IVisEventProc` interface, goes into the class module and the second part, with the Initialize method goes into a standard module.

Comment: Hi John thanks for the tip. I have manage to solve my problem.